# Download and instantly execute rather than manual trigger

Tags: html

Is there a way to instantly trigger or execute the downloaded file using html only?
Here is the simple script that I am using and this call will just simply download my app but my aim is not just simply download it but what I need is to execute directly on what I've downloaded on this link

```
href="http://localhost:8088/main/system/launch/client/MyApp.jnlp"
```

Appreciate any suggestions or commentsm TIA.

Comment: So you want to download a file and instantly run it without any input at all from the user? I sure *hope* that isn't possible.

Comment: yup correct! Oh I see, I just tried if this could be possible

Comment: Truthfully I don't have any resource that says it's definitively impossible, although I haven't really looked. I'd have to imagine, given how exploitable that would be (go to a page, page immediately downloads .exe file, instantly runs it without you doing anything), that this is not possible.

Comment: Ok got it, maybe I need to find out a better solution rather than performing this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html. The file you're trying to run is kind of like a Java applet, and will require Java to be installed on the client as well as get permission, etc. to open.

That page goes into detail about what html markup is required, particularly this part

```
Create the HTML page from which your application will be launched. Invoke Deployment Toolkit functions to deploy the Java Web Start application.
In the example, the Dynamic Tree Demo application is deployed in JavaWebStartAppPage.html.

<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src=
      "https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        // using JavaScript to get location of JNLP
        // file relative to HTML page
        var dir = location.href.substring(0,
            location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        var url = dir + "dynamictree_webstart.jnlp";
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.7.0');
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

My guess is you could simplify it by doing something like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(
            "http://localhost:8088/main/system/launch/client/MyApp.jnlp", 
            "1.7.0"
        );
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

It seems that when you run the above code, something like this appears below it:

```
<a href='javascript:if (!deployJava.isWebStartInstalled("1.7.0")) {if (deployJava.installLatestJRE()) {if (deployJava.launch("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/deployment/dynamictree_webstartJWSProject/dynamictree_webstart.jnlp")) {}}} else {if (deployJava.launch("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/deployment/dynamictree_webstartJWSProject/dynamictree_webstart.jnlp")) {}}' onmouseover="window.status=''; return true;"><img src="//java.com/js/webstart.png" border="0"></a>
```

So you might try just running a modified version of the JavaScript inside of that `href`. In your case, probably:

```
const url = "http://localhost:8088/main/system/launch/client/MyApp.jnlp";
if (!deployJava.isWebStartInstalled("1.7.0")) {
  if (deployJava.installLatestJRE()) {
    deployJava.launch(url);
  }
} else {
  deployJava.launch(url);
}
```

Comment: this is great! it's almost but still the challenge is if I trigger that button it should instantly execute the downloaded file rather than clicking it manually